# What does $A$ mean in $V = \{ X \in P(A) \mid |X| \text{ is odd}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble understanding what the $A$ stand for. That's the only place $A$ is mentioned, without knowing what it is, I can't solve the rest of the exercise.

$$V = \{ X \in P(A) \mid |X| \text{ is odd}\},$$

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have no idea, since we have even less context than you do.  Could you tell us what exactly the exercise is, and what you've done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is a set, then $P(A)$ is the collection of all subsets of $A$. This means that $V$ in your question is the collection of all subsets of $A$ that has an odd number of elements.

For example, if $A$ is the set $\{0,1,2\}$ then $V=\{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{0,1,2\}\}$.

Without further context it is hard to tell what $A$ means exactly, though. I suppose it is a general set on which you are supposed to prove some statement.

Comment: Well, yes, I need to prove that V is a vector space over the field Z2, addition is defined as symmetric difference.

Also, is the empty set {} also included in V? The cardinality of {} should be 0, which is an even number, so I would say no?

Comment: @gq3: I suppose that $A$ is given to be any nonempty set, then. Also, the empty set is indeed of even cardinality and therefore not included in $V$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, turns out it doesn't matter what A actually is, as long it doesn't contain the empty set I can prove it's not a vector space. (Multipling X ∈ V by scalar 0̅ ∈ Z₂ yields an empty set, which is not part of V)